# iOS NSFileManager Store file in Document directory using URLs not Paths?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsfilemanager

Apple says it's better to use URLs to access files stored in the phone. But I can't find a method to create a new file at URLs. Are there Any? Or we must create file using a path and retrieve them using an URL ?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need anything else but NSDocumentDirectory for your iOS application?

Comment: I'm storing the file URL in my NSManagedObject in order to retrieve the file. So it would be nice to store the file using the url

Comment: And where is that file located, then?

Comment: in the document directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To convert a file path to URL, use fileURLWithPath class method, like so:

```
NSURL *filePathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
```